# Django Rest Framework Permissions not being called for Detail and List View

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-permissions

I created this custom permission class and it does not seem to be called when I make a request from the view. I event set it to return false and requests are still successful. Tried placing a print statement to see if there would be any output but no. Not sure what I'm doing wring.

**View:**

```
class EventEditView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, JSONWebTokenAuthentication,  )
    permission_classes = (EventVisibilityPerm, )
    serializer_class = EventEditSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        event = get_object_or_404(Event, slug=kwargs['slug'])
        serializer = EventSerializer(event)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**Permissions.py:**

```
class EventVisibilityPerm(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Permission class determines whether a user has access to a specific Event
    """

def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
    user = request.user
    if obj.user == user:
        return True
```

**Serializer: **

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        exclude = ('user', 'id')
```

Currently testing permissions for this detail view but this permission will also need to be used on a List view.

Comment: seems like you should put **`authentication_classes`**

Comment: for testing purposes I left it empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **MUST** implement the [**`has_permission(self, request, view)`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions) method while creating the ***custom permission classes***.

From the [**DRF Doc**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions),

> The instance-level **`has_object_permission`** method will only be called if the view-level **`has_permission`** checks have already passed.

**Example:**

```
from rest_framework import permissions


class EventVisibilityPerm(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        """
        allowing users with specific email ids
        """
        if request.user.email in EMAIL_WHITELIST:
            return True
        return False

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        """
        allowing users those who are the owner of the object (obj.user)
        """
        return request.user == obj.user
```

Comment: I see, so what is the appropriate way of check object level values  with the has_permission method?

Comment: implement a `has_permission` method in your `EventVisibilityPerm` class in such a way that it should handle your custom permission checks. That's all

Comment: Is there an implementation that does not require using a forloop for each object in the queryset for a ListAPI?

Comment: `has_object_permission` method is invoked **only during the `Detail View`** API call. Anyway I have added a simple example, hope it helps

Comment: Okay, I've updated my code to show more. There is not a way for me to determine whether a user has access to the object without first accessing the object. 

There isn't a set field I can compare the user to from just the view level.

Comment: If you want to ***restrict the objects/instance*** shown in ListAPI, you should override the **`get_queryset()`** method of View. As I said earlier, **`has_object_permission`** method only meant for Detail View, which only handles One object per API call

Answer (score 2):

You can override two functions for the permission class, you inherit from `BasePermission`. those functions are `has_permission` and  `has_object_permission`. `has_permission` is checked automatically. but `has_object_permission` function should be called manually in your view with code below:

```
self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
```

Comment: I see, how can I check permissions for a queryset of objects? I would imagine using a forloop for each object in the set would be very inefficient.

Comment: you can use Django ORM capabilities for checking a condition in queryset if possible.